# GDB record process does not support ioctl request on ARM

Tags: gdb, record

I compiled GDB 7.8 for native debugging on my Arndale 5250 board running, linaro 3.12(2013). The GDB was configured as “arm-linux-gnueabihf” and built using statically linked libraries. 
It works fine on the board but in “record and replay mode”. It generates the following message when came across a printf statement:

```
    "Process record and replay target doesn't support ioctl request 0x7efff06c ()
    ( null)Process record: inferior program stopped.”

    [process 2169] #1 stopped.
    0x76f0f704 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
```

When proceeded further it cannot debug any more.

```
    (gdb) n 
    Cannot find bounds of current function
```

I believe its because of some missing libraries on the target platform.
Please note that when I built GDB I copied only its exe to the target Arndale board, not any libraries. I thought statically linking with libraries will do the task.
Any idea how I can run process record and replay on ARM architecture like I usually do on my x86 machine?

Answer (score 0):

gdb's process record feature works by executing each assembly instruction and recording its effects.  When a calling into the kernel, it also has to know the effects of the system call.  `ioctl` presents a singular challenge here because there are many possible `iocctl` calls.

From the description it sounds as though your libc is using an `ioctl` that gdb does not already know.  In this case there is no solution other than to implement support for that call in gdb.